# How to make multiple RDF graphs from a list of dictionaries (triples) with RDFlib in Python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, rdf, rdflib

*What I have:* A list of 20k dictionaries (triples) that need to be transformed to RDF using RDFlib.

*Goal:* For every triple, I want a new rdf Graph(). However, when I loop through all the triples, the method .add() accumulates every triple into the same graph.

*Question:* How can I make a new graph at each loop so that the graph does not accumulate data at each loop? Maybe there is a way of deleting the graph at each loop?

In the real code I am publishing every rdf-transformed triple to a service, which needs to be done one by one as it is a lot of data (20k triples). For every triple, it is its own publication so I cannot have it all in the same graph.

**My sample code (simplified) :**

```
import rdflib
from rdflib import Graph, FOAF, Literal, Namespace

list_dicts_triples = [{'subject': 'she', 'predicate': 'went', 'object': 'there'},
              {'subject': 'I', 'predicate': 'like', 'object': 'ice-cream'}]

graph = Graph()
EX = Namespace('http://example.org/')
rdf = Namespace('http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#')
graph.bind('ex', EX)

subject_rdf = rdf["subject"]
object_rdf = rdf["object"]
predicate_rdf = rdf['predicate']

for triple in list_dicts_triples:
    graph.add((subject_rdf, EX.TYPE, FOAF.Person)) #subject
    graph.add((predicate_rdf, rdflib.URIRef('http://example_predicates.com'), Literal(triple['predicate']))) #predicate
    graph.add((object_rdf, rdflib.URIRef('http://example_concepts.com'), Literal(triple['object']))) #object
    output = graph.serialize(format='ttl').decode('u8')
    print(output) #print rdf graph
```

**Current output:** (as you can see, the items of the first dictionary have been added to the second rdf graph ('there', 'went'..).

```
#graph 1
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/> .
@prefix ns1: <http://> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

rdf:object ns1:example_concepts.com "there" .
rdf:predicate ns1:example_predicates.com "went" .
rdf:subject ex:TYPE <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person> .

#graph 2
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/> .
@prefix ns1: <http://> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

rdf:object ns1:example_concepts.com "ice-cream",
        "there" .
rdf:predicate ns1:example_predicates.com "like",
        "went" .
rdf:subject ex:TYPE <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person> .
```

**Desired output:** (here, every graph represents every unique dictionary/triple of the list.

```
#graph 1
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/> .
@prefix ns1: <http://> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

rdf:object ns1:example_concepts.com "there" .
rdf:predicate ns1:example_predicates.com "went" .
rdf:subject ex:TYPE <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person> .

#graph 2
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/> .
@prefix ns1: <http://> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

rdf:object ns1:example_concepts.com "ice-cream".
rdf:predicate ns1:example_predicates.com "like".
rdf:subject ex:TYPE <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person> .
```

Comment: what's the problem with creating a new graph in each iteration?

Comment: I see that my text may have confused some users. I edited the question. The answer I was looking for is solved here below. Thanks for taking your time to read my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code above, you're not creating a new graph for every triple. Note that the declaration is *outside* the for loop. Move it inside and it should work how you want it to.

```
import rdflib
from rdflib import Graph, FOAF, Literal, Namespace

list_dicts_triples = [{'subject': 'she', 'predicate': 'went', 'object': 'there'},
              {'subject': 'I', 'predicate': 'like', 'object': 'ice-cream'}]


EX = Namespace('http://example.org/')
rdf = Namespace('http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#')


subject_rdf = rdf["subject"]
object_rdf = rdf["object"]
predicate_rdf = rdf['predicate']

for triple in list_dicts_triples:
    graph = Graph()
    graph.bind('ex', EX)
    graph.add((subject_rdf, EX.TYPE, FOAF.Person)) #subject
    graph.add((predicate_rdf, rdflib.URIRef('http://example_predicates.com'), Literal(triple['predicate']))) #predicate
    graph.add((object_rdf, rdflib.URIRef('http://example_concepts.com'), Literal(triple['object']))) #object
    output = graph.serialize(format='ttl').decode('u8')
    print(output) #print rdf graph
```